# Android build Ubuntu 16.04.1 required BlockingQueue

Tags: android-source, ubuntu-16.04, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to build the Android source **Build: LMY48M (android-5.1.1_r14)** on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Got the following error

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
public  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory threadFactory, java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler handler) { super(0,0,0,(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)null,(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)null,(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)null,(java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler)null); throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
  required: BlockingQueue<Runnable>
  found:    BlockingQueue
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

#### make failed to build some targets (01:15:26 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

I am using OpenJDK-7

P.S: I was intented to build on Ubuntu 14.04, however I am using a skylake processor that doesn't have support on Ubuntu 14.04.

However, I successfully build the same Android build on a virtual box running Ubuntu 14.04 on this same machine.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update#2**

By following @Nir Duan suggestion, I am using OracleJDK7. but as soon I run `make -j32` I am getting this error,

```
You asked for an OpenJDK 7 build but your version is
java version "1.7.0_80" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode).
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:191: *** stop.  Stop.
```

Comment: Hello , how you resolved this problem? I think make update-api must work , but I'm not sure .Please let us know how you resolved

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is because you need Oracle JDK7 and not OpenJDK-7 when building the source. 
Use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The result of `$ java -version` should be this:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

(If not look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/121673/570100) and change default java version)